# Project a point onto a line feature at a given angle in PostGIS - ST_Project only works for geography?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a point, a line and a known angle. I want to project the point onto the line at that angle. In the below picture, I want to find the red point:

[image]

I think this may be possible by somehow using [ST_Project](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html), but it seems that it only works with geoography, not geometry. Even the example on the doc page says:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(0 0)'::geography, 100000, radians(45.0)));

                 st_astext
--------------------------------------------
 POINT(0.635231029125537 0.639472334729198)
(1 row)
```

So, projecting a point by 100000 meters puts it at (0.635231029125537 0.639472334729198), which is definitely not right in a cartesian system.

Is there any way to wrangle it into use for geometry instead?

Comment: the point is projected in geographic coordinates, and in the example the CRS is omitted; transform your point into EPSG:4326, cast to *geography*, project using your values, cast to *geometry* and transform to your initial cartesian CRS. for your use case, however, you would need to *accurately* know the distance of the point on the line you are looking for...or make the distance longer, create a line from the initial point and the projected, and find its intersection with the other line.

Comment: also, `ST_Project` uses true north as origin for the azimuth, thus you'll need to add 90° to your values.

Comment: so, did you get this to work?

Comment: Sorry @ThingumaBob, I got caught up in some other business over the weekend. In the meantime I had implemented a manual solution where I just used basic trigonometry to cast the rays, but I will give your solution a try later on tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example of how to get results with `ST_Project`, running

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(
         ST_MakeLine(
           ST_Transform(
             ST_Project(
               ST_Transform(
                 pt.geom,
                 4326
               )::geography,
               ST_MaxDistance(ln.geom, pt.geom),
               radians(<angle_+_90°>)
             )::geometry,
             <projected_SRID>
           ),
           pt.geom
         ),
         ln.geom
       ) AS geom
FROM point AS pt,
     line AS ln
```

would give you that point by reprojecting your geometries into EPSG:4326, casting them to *geography* type, projecting the point with a distance value determined by `ST_MaxDistance` between the initial point and the line (Note: distance units will be returned in CRS units, `ST_Project` treats units as *meter*; either your initial CRS has meter as units or you´ll need to reproject yet again...) and finding the intersection point between the created line and your initial line.
The measured azimuth on the projected data will be slightly off due to the conversions between geographical and projected CRS; `ST_Project` and the *geography* type works with spheroidal algebra. To avoid that, maybe work with geographic CRS from the beginning.

Comment: Alright this is great. my first attempt involved me doing the trigonometry myself but I was running into other issues, probably unrelated ones but an adaption of your solution into my system works more reliabily, thanks for taking the time to package it up. It is strange to me that there is no such function that works on geometry. I feel like maybe doing the trigonometry with the geometry might be slightly more performant because you would avoid all these transformations but this will get the job done, thanks again.